# Stata: plotting the random+fixed effects of slopes after multilevel models are fit with `xtmixed`

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, scatterplot

I am fitting a linear multilevel model of the following form:

```
Y = b0 * X0 + b1 * X1 + b2 * X2 + b3 * X3 + u
b0 = e0
b3 = e3
```

The units in the first level are 10000 students and the clusters of the second level are 30 schools.

So, what I am trying to do is to plot each of the 30 versions of `b3`, i.e. the random effects slope of each cluster. I also need to plot that if confidence intervals of any type.

In R, I know how to do it. Assuming the model fitted is saved in the `mymodel` object, one can get the random + fixed effects of a multilevel model in R as follows:

```
#This will extract simulated random effects from the model:
myranef <- ranef(arm::sim(mymodel, 1000))
myranef <- as.data.frame(myranef)
myranef <- myranef[,grep("X3",colnames(bb))]

#This will extract simulated fixed effects from the model:
myfixef <- as.data.frame(fixef(arm::sim(mymodel, 1000)))
names(myfixef) <- names(fixef(mymodel))

#Sum random and fixed effects
for(c in 1:ncol(myranef)){
  myranef[,c] <- myranef[,c] + myfixef[,"X3"]
}
```

In the end, each column of `myranef` represents one of the 30 schools and each line is one of the 1000 simulation-iterations. From then on, it's easy to make the plot using the mean or median of each col and the desired percentiles of each col.

My problem is how to achieve a similar thing in Stata. I guess I should start by doing the following:

```
predict re*, reffects  //  linear predictor for the random effects
predict fe, xb         // linear predictor for the fixed effects
```

However, then I don't know how to:

1) get the combined version of random and fixed effects for each of the 30 schools
2) get a version with confidence intervals of some sort

Would anyone be able to kindly shed some light on how to proceed in Stata similarly to what I have in R?